# error - System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, foreach, google-geocoder

I get this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

when running this code:

```
foreach(var row in data)
{
     string strAddr = row.ADDRESS1 + "," + row.CITY + "," + row.ST;

     GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse myCoordenadas = new GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse();
     myCoordenadas = GoogleMapsDll.GoogleMaps.GetGeoCodedResults(strAddr);

     string strLat = myCoordenadas.Results[0].Geometry.Location.Lat.ToString();  
     string strLong = myCoordenadas.Results[0].Geometry.Location.Lng.ToString();

     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); 

}
```

I am not sure exactly what it means or how I might go about fixing it. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not getting any `Results` back from your API call

Comment: Try debugging. Also, [try searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IndexOutOfRangeException) and perhaps there is another question that is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually thrown by indexing operators like x[12]. You happen to have that: `Results[0]`. So it must mean that the array is actually empty, it doesn't even have a zero index. By the way, run your code in a debugger and see where exactly the exception is thrown.